# Can't add a domain name to the domain list

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am trying to add my domain to the domain list but an error is always coming and i can't seem to understand why. The error is not clear and i found nothing in the documentation that can help me to solve the problem...

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et1fd.png)

Any help would really be appreciated.